# Copying content of one sheet to a number of newly created sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on the file where:

- First, from a given list created a number of sheets with the names on the list (accounts)
- Second, from the destination "Master" sheet, all the content should be copied to each of the new sheets

While I succeeded in creating a list of new sheets (thanks to this website), I am stuck with the content of each sheet. Do not know how to fill in each new sheet with identical content which is located in the sheet "Master". The sheet "Master" has certain format, formulas, and buttons so I need to make sure that each new sheet has exctly the same layout and content. Any suggestions how to incorporate it into below macro?

```
Sub CreateSheetsFromAList()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range
    Set MyRange = Sheets("Cost Center").Range("A2")
    Set MyRange = Range(MyRange, MyRange.End(xlDown))
    For Each MyCell In MyRange
        Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) 'creates a new worksheet
        Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = MyCell.Value ' renames the new worksheet
    Next MyCell
    Sheets("Instruction").Select
    Range("A1").Select

    ErrorHandler:
    Sheets("Instruction").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Exit Sub
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: if what you want to do is to add a new sheet identical to a master sheet (identical in everything) then just copy the master sheet and rename it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is pretty close! To copy the contents of the "Master" sheet, replace

`Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)`

with

`Sheets("Master").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)`

Trust this helps.

Comment: Thanks guys, I opted ASKhan's option (a bit simpler:)). All works nicely!

Answer (score 0):

If the answer to my comment is yes, then you can try this:

```
Dim ws, new_ws as WorkSheet 'declare the worksheet

Set ws = Thisworkbook.Sheets("MasterSheet") 'set as mastersheet

For Each MyCell In MyRange
    Set new_ws = ws.copy Before:=Thisworkbook.Sheets(1) 'creates a new worksheet
    new_ws.Name = MyCell.Value 'rename it based on list
Next MyCell
```

Hope this helps.